# Stratified Sampling in Python without using any Machine Learning

Tags: python

I have a dataset that contains : ("wordsList" and "classList" file).

wordsList file contains 72 pre-processed emails. Each line is a list of words extracted from each email.

The classList file contains the class labels that indicating whether the emails are ordinary or adverts (0 for ordinary and 1 for adverts).

My task is to develop a Naïve Bayesian classifier as an email filter in Python. Namely, the classifier predicts whether emails are ordinary or adverts.

To develop this I need to use stratified sampling to select 66 out of 72 lines for training and the remaining 6 lines for the test. Then return the classification probabilities of these 6 records.
But the bad news for me is that I can't use any machine learning library, and only can use NumPy and SciPy.

Is there any way to implement this? And if so is there any sample code that implements this method from scratch? Thank you in advance!

[image: classList file]

[image: wordsList file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `groupby` method of  pandas and then to apply sampling with `frac=0.91` to get 66 lines out of the 72 in your case:

```
cL2=cL.groupby(['classList']).apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.91))
```

This creates a MultiIndex dataframe that is turned to a normal one by reseting index, dropping the column 'classList' associated to the `groupby` method, and optionally dropping an extra one (named in reference to the number of grouping variables, `level_1` here):

```
cL3=cL2.drop(columns=['classList']).reset_index().drop(columns=['level_1'])
```

Comment: i've tried putting it, and it shows KeyError : 'classList'

Comment: It looks like the name of the varaible is not in the data set. I proposed this name as the grouping variable because you mentioned that  your table contains "wordsList" and "classList". Use the exact name you will find with a command `cL.info()`

Comment: Ohh btw, how do I return the classification probabilities of the 6 test records?

Comment: This will depend on the package you will use. You should find the answer in other SO posts on ML.